# How to save NSURLRequest so batch send at a later time

Tags: ios

I would like to send small post requests, but I don't want to do it every few minutes. Is there a way to save 10 at a time, and once it hits 10, then they can all be sent?

Some sort of queue?

Here is how I'm structuring my requests:

```
//Init request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
                                    requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    //Set headers
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

        //get the http headers
        NSHTTPURLResponse* newResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
        NSString *contentType = [newResp allHeaderFields][@"Content-Type"];
        contentType = [contentType lowercaseString];

        //serialize if content type is JSON
        if ([WFHttp string:contentType contains:@"json"]) {
            response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
        }

        if (connectionError) {
            NSLog(@"%@",connectionError);
        }

        //send completion
        completion(response);

    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you store the requests in an array that's stored in user defaults and whenever you create a new request add it to that array. Once there are 10 requests, send them all out and clear them out of user defaults.

Comment: Seems simple enough. I was just wondering if there was a NSURLRequest capability or something similar